# How to wait until user clicks Accept/Cancel button or closes authorization window

Tags: javascript, html

I am opening a URL for LinkedIn authorization in a pop-up window & after a user allows us to get his profile details. **I want to copy the window URL & redirect it back to the parent window.**

I know how we get the window URL but struggling with how we can wait for the user to either cancel the authorization or allow & then get the window URL. Any leads on how this can be achieved?

Want to get the window URL because it contains the access code which can further be used to retrieve user details using LinkedIn APIs.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // The url is opened in new pop up window, then user enter his credentials & gets a authorization window with allow & cancel button. 
  var win = window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=XXX&state=aRandomString&scope=r_emailaddress", "LinkedIn Authorization", 'height=700,width=900');

  // Before printing the console log, I want to wait for the above line of code to either wait for close/allow/cancel button to be clicked on the authorization.
  console.log(win.location.href);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">LinkedIn connect</button>
```

Comment: You can `postMessage` from the popup window after LinkedIn redirects the user after success login. Something like `const win = window.open('..linkedin')` -> success login -> Linkedin Redirect to yoursite.com so `win.location.href` is what you need -> `window.opener.postMessage(params)`. There is a good post (React version but understandable) https://medium.com/@geekrodion/react-and-linkedin-authorization-47b2395ba785

Comment: This article does make sense but I am new to frontend development, on top of it working on a Wordpress website. I don't really know how to embed react code in HTML. I am trying to do the same steps done with react in javascript. Thanks for the article :)